# Capturing Key Events of DefaultCellEditor Component

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keyboard-events, tablecelleditor

When It writes about an cell of a `JTable`, without this cell is in editing state. Ie, when it is shown with a blue background colour. The cell will enter to edition mode and the text writed is showed at end of current text of the editor component (a `TextField`).

However, in this state the `TextField` of the `DefaultCellEditor` has not the focus still. And the key events doesn't belong to the textfield.

What component is the receiver of these key events?
How can I capture this key events?

Comment: Why are you trying to capture the key events?

Answer (score 0):

The component that receive the events before that EditorComponent get the focus is the JTable itself.

The JTable passes the key events to the editor component of the selected cell via key binding through the processKeyBinding method. 
For this reason no key event listeners are notified

My problem was that my custom editor had not the processKeyBinding because it was a JPanel (composed editor). Then the Key events was lost.

The solution is pass the processKeyBinding action using a custom TextField with a puclic function to do this feature.

```
public class KeyBindingTextField extends JTextField {
    protected boolean processKeyBindingPublic(KeyStroke ks, KeyEvent e, int condition, boolean pressed) {
        return super.processKeyBinding(ks, e, condition, pressed);
    }  
}
```

Then, I pass the key binding method to TextField from JPanel so:

```
  protected boolean processKeyBinding(KeyStroke ks, KeyEvent e, int condition, boolean pressed) {
     return TextField.processKeyBindingPublic(ks, e, condition, pressed);
  }
```